# Featured Meta.SE post shows on main sidebar but not meta

Tags: bug, sidebar, featured-questions

Today the post [Setting Up a HackerOne Security Bug Bounty Program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297423/setting-up-a-hackerone-security-bug-bounty-program) shows up on the sidebar on the main site

[image]

But, when you visit meta, it is missing

[image]

Is this a bug or do we not show the featured Meta.SE post on Meta.SO?

Comment: Meta.SE posts are indeed not shown here; I think that's pretty much by design. That's the same across all main/meta combinations, the Meta.SE features are only shown on the main sites. Compare [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) with [Meta.CR](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the info.  Delete the Q or should we [status-bydesign] it?

Comment: I know sites have knobs to tune that side-bar, but that's a CM-level feature (us elected mods can't see it). So I'm going with *propably* [meta-tag:status-bydesign] and wait for a CM to confirm.